# iPhone 6 - Dictation mispelled

Tags: iphone, voice-dictation

When using dictation, I can't make it spell my wife's first and our last names correctly.  I have tried entering phonetic & pronunciation fields, to no avail.
Wife's name is Rindy, but dictation ALWAYS writes Randy.  Last name is Hoke, but it always writes one of 3 other variations.   Grrr...very annoying

Any suggestions?

Comment: This happens to me, too. I've reverted to using nicknames for people the system doesn't understand. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: You can try by saying to Siri " You're pronouncing [person's] name wrong." It might add pronunciation with the word.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your wife has her own card in your address book. Then open up an email message and start dictating, saying things like:

"Rindy is my wife *period*."

"Rindy is a person *period*."

"I am meeting with Rindy today."

"Where is Rindy *questionmark*"

Each time the computer misspells Rindy's name, go back and correct it. Eventually you will show the computer whose boss, and it will start to spell Rindy's name properly. (Really: there appears to be an algorithm that looks at spelling corrections and uses this as feedback on dictation.)